# Why do I need multiple segments to model the RC flight time of interconnect?

Tags: delay, vlsi, interconnect

Consider a problem where we are interested in computing the delay for a signal to propagate to some load capacitance after a step input on the driving logic gate, and let there be a nonnegligible interconnect load with its own resistance \$R_{wire}\$ and capacitance \$C_{wire}\$. Of course, this interconnect is a distributed circuit, but my understanding is that it can (with no approximation) be modelled as \$N \to \infty\$ lumped \$\Pi\$ RC networks, with R and C in each network equal to \$R_{wire}/N\$ and \$C_{wire}/2N\$. Further, one has that the Elmore delay of any number \$M\$ \$\Pi\$ segments used to model the wire equals \$R_{wire}C_{wire}/2\$. It then seems to follow that if we are interested in computing the RC flight time for a wire we can just use *one* \$\Pi\$ segment to model its effect. Why then do we often use more than one segment when we want a closer approximation to the actual wire? I can kind of understand it if we want to know the delay until a certain part of the wire is charged up, but if we are just interested in the delay until we reach the end of the wire?

As an example of what I mean, consider the example below taken from Weste and Harris's *CMOS VLSI Design*. I emphasize that they choose to use two \$\Pi\$ segments on one of the paths. Why is this choice necessary or a better approximation to the real situation given my above discussion?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following single RC delay stage: -

[image]

The phase lag of the output appears to be linear with frequency and, when this happens we get a constant time lag i.e. the circuit adds a delay to the signal. But, if we plotted the phase lag beyond 1 MHz we would see problems: -

[image]

This time I've plotted up to 10 MHz and, as you can see, the phase lag is not actually very linear with frequency and, if you had a wideband signal you would get serious distortion of the waveform shape.

That is why we would use \$N\$ stages of RC. Each stage would have an RC product that is \$N\$ times smaller. The result is that we achieve a much wider bandwidth for the same time delay with much less signal-shape distortion.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! I guess what I'm hoping to clarify is whether the problem you've noted also persists for \$\Pi\$ networks. (I believe) you've shown that a single \$L\$ segment does a poor job of modelling an RC distributed wire, but is this the case for the \$\Pi\$ case too?

Comment: @EE18 It's the same for either because you can remodel a pi section as an L section just by moving the left hand capacitor into the stage before. In other words, it makes no real difference whether you analyse as pi or L.

Comment: I am still not sure I follow, apologies. Just to be sure, are you saying that increasing the number of segments will get us closer to the true waveform which emerges for the real distributed circuit, whereas using a single segment will give you the wrong waveform even if (if we use a \$Pi\$ network where \$RC/2\$ is correctly the propagation delay rather than \$RC\$ as in an \$L\$ network) the propagation delay we recover with a single segment is correct?

Comment: Each segment can only produce a maximum phase shift of 90 degrees so, what you want is the ability to produce a phase shift that is infinite at infinite frequency but, obviously, that requires an infinite number of stages so we make a compromise and use enough stages to get a reasonably linear phase shift vs frequencies up to as high as we need.

Comment: Got it. To confirm, does my previous comment sort of capture the gist of your comment? Just want to be sure I understand before acccepting.

Comment: Your comment tries to capture the whole picture and, in doing so (in my opinion), fails to deliver a memorable meaning. For instance, the use of the word "which" in the first sentence confuses me. Hence, my previous comment just targeted what I consider to be the legitimate facts and left it for you to glue the bits together. So, you are asking me (in effect) if I prefer your way of writing things or, my way of writing things and, of course you know the answer!!! Stick to direct questions @EE18

Comment: Using the example of R = 10 and C = 10 nF in my answer, you can clearly see a reliable and consistent time delay of 100 ns up to 100 kHz. At 1 MHz, this has dropped slightly to 92 ms. At 2 MHz it has dropped to about 72 ns and, we are on a slippery slope. So, if you want to maintain excellent signal integrity at the output, you probably would not use the single stage at frequencies above 100 kHz.

Comment: @EE18 if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: Sorry, this one slipped by me. I am just rereading now and I'm still not sure I understand. As I say in the OP, "It seems to follow that if we are interested in computing the RC flight time for a wire we can just use one \$\Pi\$
 segment to model its effect [because both a distributed wire and this one lumped \$\Pi\$ segment lead to the same \$RC/2\$ delay]. Why then do we often use more than one segment when we want a closer approximation to the actual wire?" That is, whether we use one segment, three segments, five segments, or the real distributed wire, the delay is \$RC/2\$.

Comment: @EE18 if you look at the phase response of an RC circuit versus increasing frequency, you can see that it starts linearly at DC to some value of frequency where linearity is just starting to be eroded. In the above diagrams that might be argued to be around 1 MHz. In other words at 100 kHz, the phase lag is 3.6 degrees (equivalent to 10 ns) and, at 1 MHz it's probably closer to 32 degrees (equivalent to about 8.9 ns. As frequency rises the equivalent time delay gets shorter more rapidly hence, we choose a frequency where we must limit a single stage acting as a reliable delay. OK so far?

Comment: ....to get a a higher bandwidth (say 10 MHz as opposed to 1 MHz) we must choose an RC time constant that is one-tenth of what was used in the above pictures (10 ns). So, we choose an RC time of 1 ns. We do this to avoid the phase response getting non-linear (because that shortens the time delay we want) BUT, to restore a full 10 ns time delay, we have to cascade ten 1 ns sections. That would achieve a  fairly flat 10 ns time delay up to 10 MHz.

Comment: OK, I think I understand and have accepted. Feel free to ignore the following: I'm just writing it for me/for posterity, but also feel free to clarify if you feel I've erred. (1) In my question above, I wrote "whether we use one segment, three segments, five segments, or the real distributed wire, the delay is /2". There is no contradiction with what Andy has written because that claim is true (if and) only if  we are approximating delay with the Elmore approximation. (2) If we are rigorously modelling an RC circuit then we must proceed as Andy says. Imagine we have a signal with...

Comment: ... frequency content up to some \$f_h\$. We must ensure that our \$RC\$ network gives this delay all the way up to \$f_h\$ and so, per the argument Andy gives, we must use some number of segments to achieve this. Note that the times which Andy alludes to above as corresponding to a given phase delay \$\phi\$ are computed as \$t_{delay} = \phi/\omega\$ where \$\omega\$ is the radian frequency.

Comment: @EE18 correct except I would say that if you were truly trying to model (or replicate) a wire, you would use LC segments (because they give a higher usable bandwidth for a given delay with almost zero amplitude modification vs frequency).